# Parsing Vobject vcard telephones by type

Tags: vobject

I am trying to parse vCard Objects and i am having issues getting the different types of telephones or addresses i.e home or work.
I  can only get the first instance but not the second instance of phone.

```
TEL;TYPE=work,voice;VALUE=uri:tel:+11115551
TEL;TYPE=home,voice;VALUE=uri:tel:+14045551

contact = vobject.readOne(s, allowQP=True)
print contact.tel.type_param
print contact.tel
```

Both of those work but they only give me the first phone number.
I want to do something like below, but of course this gives me an error.

```
print contact.tel.type_param.home
print contact.tel.work.value
```

What is the best way to access vCard objects by type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vobject is not documented very well. From the method doctring : """Return a child's value (the first, by default), or None."""

So to fix it, i had to specify a childnumber other than Zero.

```
 print contact.getChildValue('tel',default = None, childNumber = 0)
 print contact.getChildValue('tel',default = None, childNumber = 1)
```